# Filter models by multiples conditions in Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to filter a list of products. The API is accessible in the route /q, I pass the filtering parameters like this /q?location=1,2&category=1,2,3 (if no arguments are passed, it will fetch all locations/categories.

```
public function getProductsByQuery()
{
    $commaSeparatedLocations = Input::get('location');
    $commaSeparatedCategories = Input::get('category');


    if ($commaSeparatedLocations == null){
        $numberOfLocations = Location::count();
        for ($i=0;$i<=$numberOfLocations;$i++)
        {
            $locationsArray[$i] = $i;
        }
    } else {
        $locationsArray = $this->toArray($commaSeparatedLocations);
    }

    if ($commaSeparatedCategories == null){
        $numberOfCategories = Category::count();
        for ($i=0;$i<=$numberOfCategories;$i++)
        {
            $categoriesArray[$i] = $i;
        }
    } else {
        $categoriesArray = $this->toArray($commaSeparatedCategories);
    }

    return $products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $categoriesArray)->whereIn('location_id', $locationsArray)->paginate(config('app.products_per_page'));
}

public function toArray($commaSeparatedString)
{
    return explode(",",$commaSeparatedString);
}
```

And well, it works. But I was wondering how can I improve my code. There must be a smarter way where not that many SQL queries are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks much more readable to me:

```
public function getProductsByQuery()
{
    $q = Product::query();

    if (request('location')) {
        $q->whereIn('location_id', $this->toArray(request('location')));
    }

    if (request('category')) {
        $q->whereIn('category_id', $this->toArray(request('category')));
    }

    return $q->paginate(config('app.products_per_page'));
}
```

Comment: That's genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It was so interesting, where (or how) can I find more information about this? Because this query() method is not in the official documentation. Thanks, again.

Comment: @JorgeAnzola you'll not find this in the docs, but you can look into the source code to understand how it works. `query()` is a method in `Model` class which is just creating a new query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a more complex query / with more parameters, you should have a look at https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter

Answer (score 1):

This is best way to filter sql query in laravel.

```
    $q = Product::query();

    $q->when(request('location'), function ($q) {
        return $q->where('location', request('location'));
    });

    $q->when(request('category'), function ($q) {
        return $q->where('category', request('category'));
    });


    $data['product_list'] = $q->paginate(5);
                 //OR
    $data['product_list'] = $q->get(5);
```